# Getting callback from widgets instantiated with for-loop - Flutter

Tags: flutter

**Background:** I am instantiating a series of card items in a stateful widget tree using `for (var card in menuLists[_selectedIndex]) card` This is creating a series of card widgets that I can scroll through. Each of the cards also has an add-to-cart button that navigates to a new page where a user will click a subsequent add-to-cart button that should then increment a counter Text() widget on the page where the cards are first instantiated, as well as do a few other things cart related.

**Counter Text() Widget:**

```
int numberOfItemsInCart;

Text(
     numberOfItemsInCart.toString(),
     style: GoogleFonts.ubuntuMono(fontSize: 23),
),
```

In the first button, there is an onPressed() as shown below that awaits a callback variable from a `Navigator.onPop(context, 'variable')` that is triggered on the second page by the second add-to-cart button being clicked.

**First add-to-cart button:**

```
bool doAddItemToCart = false;

MaterialButton(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                              ),
                              child: Text(
                                'Add to Cart',
                                style: GoogleFonts.ubuntuCondensed(
                                  fontSize: 17,
                                  color: colorPalette.chooseColor('white'),
                                ),
                              ),
                              color: colorPalette.chooseColor('lightGreen'),
                              onPressed: () async {
                                doAddItemToCart = await Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => AddToCart(
                                        menuItemName, menuItemOptions),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
```

**Second add-to-cart button:**

```
Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Wrap(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
                    child: MaterialButton(
                      minWidth: 296,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                      ),
                      color: colorPalette.chooseColor('darkGrey'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {

                        });
                        Navigator.pop(context, /*boolValue*/);
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          SnackBar(
                            backgroundColor:
                                colorPalette.chooseColor('offWhite'),
                            duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                            content: Text(
                              'Item added to cart',
                              style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                                color: colorPalette.chooseColor('darkGrey'),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          'Add to Cart!',
                          style: GoogleFonts.ubuntuCondensed(
                            fontSize: 23,
                            color: colorPalette.chooseColor('white'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Essentially, I need to communicate the doAddItemToCart boolean value to the stateful widget, which contains the list of card widgets, that, based on its value, will increment the counter or not.

**Problem:** The problem is that I don't know how to get the values returned to the individual cards from the second add-to-cart button's Navigator.pop() and subsequently increment the counter Text() widget. I considered using global variables but that is kind of frowned upon. I also considered using an inherited widget, but I don't this I need to go there. I am new to Flutter and Dart btw so please have mercy. Does anyone know an easy workaround for this? Please let me know if I should provide more clarification.

Comment: could you post the whole code?

Comment: @SrilalSachintha Added the button widgets for you.

Comment: Without inherited, there are very little options. either save the values to local storage which is not that good option and just use a Global variable. best way would be to use https://pub.dev/packages/get GetX. make the globle varible a obs varible with getX and you wont need to worry about states.

Comment: @SrilalSachintha Inherited doesn't seem to allow one to modify the inherited value though which is what I need since the card is the child widget and not the inherited widget. I need to be able to send the bool value to the parent widget from each of the cards.

Comment: you could use a fullscreen dialog though. that way you can return a value easily.

Comment: @SrilalSachintha GetX did the trick! Didn't need the globals at all and very easy to implement.

Comment: I'm glad you did!

Answer (score 0):

`The problem is that I don't know how to get the values returned to the individual cards from the second add-to-cart button's Navigator.pop() and subsequently increment the counter Text() widget.`

Instead of sending an item name and option, you can send your Item object to add cart.

So, instead of this:

```
doAddItemToCart = await Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => AddToCart(
                                        menuItemName, menuItemOptions),
                                  ),
                                );
```

change to:

```
selectedItem = await Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => AddToCart(
                                        item, menuItemOptions),
                                  ),
                                );
```

where `item`, is your object item.

then, when you adding the item to the cart, include it when popping:

```
Navigator.pop(context, item);
```

Now, you can check if the navigator returning a selected item or not:

```
selectedItem = await Navigator.push(...);
if(selectedItem != null & selectedItem is YourItemObject) {
    // Add to cart.
}
```